# How do I get a http address for a file on my hard drive? or how do I upload the file to a free image hosting and get the url programmatically?

Tags: c#, image, url, hosting

Have a file on my hard drive. But the API program I am using only accepts hosted files. It needs a URL, not a directory address on my computer.

Can someone suggest how I can get around this?

I tried giving the program an address like below, but it didn't work:
     file://localhost/c|/images/myImage.jpg

I was thinking I might have to upload the file to an image hosting website and then get a copy of the image URL.

Does anyone know what site to use or what code to use? or any other work-around?

(the image only needs to be there for about 1 minute)

Thanks a lot for reading

Comment: Can you share with us what 'API program' you are using?

Comment: you can use dropBox, just place your files in the public folder

Comment: I am using eBay API. I will look into dropBox to see if I can upload them programmatically, thanks.

Comment: @Danny yeah its very easy to use , do you need more details

Comment: Thanks @meda Its ok i found some info, just looking into it to see if its easier than flicker, I'm quite new to programming

Comment: Long shot...Have you seen this? https://ebay.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/320/~/options-for-adding-pictures-to-an-item  The post mentions eBay Windows SDK and shows an image upload sample using filesystem paths as the inputs.  Hope that helps -- but you're probably in some other part the API.

Comment: Thank you @David. I was able to upload the pictures for the the gallery photo not for the variations. The API for the variations seems different. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample (new June 2013) I think might be what you are looking for:

**C#.NET code sample to Upload images from local system to EPS using eBayPictureService**|

https://ebay.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2196/kw/Upload%20pictures%20.Net%20SDK

Comment: Thanks @David this is actually what I needed. It works great!!! :) Did you suspect I meant eBay before? Maybe you just know everything about all API ;) I didn't mention eBay at the start because I looked into it a lot a couple of months ago but couldn't find the information you gave. I think its just recently published. Anyway thanks again

Comment: @Danny The google god was good to me tonight.  Accepting my answer would be much appreciated.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [C# API for Flickr](http://flickrnet.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Karl. Sorry I cant up-vote anyone yet because i don't have 15 reputation